# Highlight associated Label when DatePicker/ListView has focus via tabbing

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, label

As I tab from field to field in my WPF app, I highlight the label associated with each field.  This works fine for ComboBox and TextBox items but NOT for ListViews or DatePickers.  I'm utilizing the IsFocused path portion in the binding part of the Label Tag (see code below).

```
<Label
    Style="{StaticResource styleLabelTextBlockLeft}"
    Target="{Binding ElementName=dpBrthDt}"
    Tag="{Binding ElementName=dpBrthDt, Path=(IsFocused)}"
>
    <TextBlock 
         TextWrapping="Wrap">When were you born?
    </TextBlock>                                  
</Label>
<DatePicker
    x:Name="dpBrthDt"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    SelectedDate="{Binding
        Path=CurrentEntity.BrthDt, 
        Mode=TwoWay, 
        ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
        NotifyOnValidationError=True
    }"
    Width="115"
/>
```

Any ideas why the Binding portion of the Tag that references IsFocused works on TextBoxes/ComboBoxes and not DatePickers/ListViews?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because `ListViews` and `DatePickers` contain multiple elements inside them, so the `IsFocused` element is something inside the control, and not the actual control itself.

Use the property `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` instead of `IsFocused` and it should work